# How to toggle React component using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to toggle (show/hide) react component with redux toolkit but i can not get the value of "toggle",redux toolkit useSelector is not working. it showing "undefined".

**this code is not working.please put your suggestion about my mistakes.i need your help..please help me.**
[image]
**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { store, persistor } from "./app/store.js";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import ToggleButton from './components/ToggleButton/ToggleButton';
import ToggleExample from './components/ToggleExample/ToggleExample';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='example'>
      <ToggleExample/>
      <ToggleButton/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**toggleSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const initialState = {
    toggle: false
}
export const toggleSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'toggleSidebar',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        toggleVisible: (state) => {
            state.toggle = false
            console.log("state.toggle 1",state.toggle)
        },
        toggleInvisible: (state) => {
            state.toggle = true
            console.log("state.toggle 2",state.toggle)
        },
    }
})
export const { 
  toggleVisible, 
  toggleInvisible
 } = toggleSlice.actions;
 export const selectToggle = (state) => state.toggle;
export default toggleSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import toggleSlice from '../feature/toggleSlice'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import {
  persistReducer, persistStore, FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, toggleSlice)


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    persistedReducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

**ToggleButton.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleVisible,toggleInvisible, selectToggle } from '../../feature/toggleSlice';
import './ToggleButton.css'
const ToggleButton = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const  toggle  = useSelector(selectToggle)
  console.log(toggle)  
  const handleToggle = () => { 
   { toggle ?  dispatch(toggleVisible()) : dispatch(toggleInvisible()) }
}

  return (
    <div className='toggle-button-div'>
    <button className='toggle-button' onClick={() => handleToggle()}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ToggleButton
```

**ToggleExample.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './ToggleExample.css';
const ToggleExample = () => {
  return (
    <div className='toggle-example'>
    <ul>
        <li className='list-style'>Home</li>
        <li className='list-style'>About</li>
        <li className='list-style'>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ToggleExample
```

Comment: You can try changing `reducer: {
    persistedReducer
  },` to `reducer: persistedReducer`

Comment: it would be easier to debug your code if you can put it on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a instanse of button using useRef hook let say btnRef is the instance and dispatch that instance to reducer then you can toggle it using **btnRef.current.click()**

Comment: Why would anybody do this?